# OpenGL/ How can I stop glutTimerFunc?

Tags: animation, opengl

I want to make my human figure walk when I press '0', and stop when I press '0' again.
I managed to make it walk as I want, but I do not know the way to stop glutTimerFunc.

Is there any OpenGL function that makes `glutTimerFunc` stop?

And here is my code.

```
if (key == '0') {
    if (!walk_working_flag) {//when walk does not working
        walk();
        walk_working_flag = true;
    }
    else {
        //stop walking
        glutTimerFunc(100, stop_animation , 0);
    }
}
```

in `stop_animation function`, no rotation occurs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the API docs](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html):

> There is no support for canceling a registered callback. Instead,
>   ignore a callback based on its value parameter when it is triggered.